# why does this function return garbage value

Tags: c, function, pointers

I was writing a program and facing this problem that the following function used to return garbage values:

```
int* foo(int temp){
   int x = temp;
   return &x;
}
```

When I modified it to this, it worked fine:

```
int* foo(int *temp){
    int *x = temp;
    return x
}
```

What was wrong with the first version?

Comment: I'm not sure about a C-tagged one, but the story is pretty amusing and it's the same problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6441218/can-a-local-variables-memory-be-accessed-outside-its-scope

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The first version returns a reference to a local variable `x` whose storage is limited to the function `foo`. When the function exits, `x` can no longer be used. Returning a reference to it is one instance of a *dangling pointer*.

In the second version, you're really only passing in and returning the same pointer value, which refers to memory which *isn't* limited by the lifetime of the function. So even after the function exits, the returned address is still valid.

Another alternative:

```
int *foo(int temp)
{
    int *x = malloc(sizeof(int));
    *x = temp;
    return x;
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Do you mean using variables which are object members?

Comment: If you are referring to structs or C++ objects, it depends on whether they are allocated on the stack or the heap.

Comment: When you intent to return a pointer to an integer (`int*`), you either need to have the member already allocated before calling the function, or allocate new memory using `malloc()`. You should **never return the pointer to a local variable as function output**.

Comment: @pb2q Scope and storage duration are different things, a variable can go out of scope but its storage could still exist.

Comment: @ouah I don't believe that I've confused the difference in my answer. If I have, suggest a re-wording?

Comment: @pb2q `void foo(void) { int x, *bla = &x; bar(bla); }` In `bar` function `x` is also no longer in scope but `bar` has the right to modify `x`. I think scope has nothing to do with this issue.

Answer (score 0):

For each function there will be an activation record, which will be created in stack once the execution of that function starts. Activation record holds all the local variables also. And this activation record will be freed once the function execution finishes.

So if we return an address of a local variable means, that will be freed memory of previous function`s activation record. Dereferencing that memrory is an undefined behaviour.

In the below case, function `foo` is returning the `&x` that means `p` will holds the address of `func`'s local variable `x`. This is valid. But if function `func` tries to retrun `p`(address of `x`) which is not valid.

```
int* func
{
   int x;
   int *p;
   ...
   p = foo(&x);
   //using p is valid here
   ...
   return p; //This is invalid
}

int* foo(int *temp)
{
   int *x = temp;
   return x //This is valid
}
```

In the below case, funciton `foo` is returning address of its local variable `x` to function `func`. So `p` will holds address of `foo`'s local variable. So deferencing `p` is invalid because `foo` functions execution has been completed and its activation record is freed.

```
int* func
{
   int x;
   int *p;
   ...
   p = foo(x);
   //using p is invalid here
   ...
   return p; //This is invalid
}

int* foo(int temp)
{
   int x = temp;
   return &x; //This is also invalid
}
```