# Very simple C++ basic code

Tags: c++

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can a local variable's memory be accessed outside its scope?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6441218/can-a-local-variables-memory-be-accessed-outside-its-scope)
>   [why does this function return garbage value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12042538/why-does-this-function-return-garbage-value)

Why does this simple code return garbage?

```
char *output()
{
    char o[2] = "A";
    return o;
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << output(); 
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6441218/can-a-local-variables-memory-be-accessed-outside-its-scope See here for the definitive answer to using function variables out of scope.

Comment: and this one also should be helpful http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18584/how-to-ask-a-smart-question

Comment: Your compiler should have also warned you about using the address of a local variable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because you return a pointer to invalid memory - `o` is destroyed when `output` returns.

You have several options:

- allocate memory dynamically (using `malloc`), copy `"A"` into this memory and return its address
- directly return string literal: `return "A";`

P.S. Of course, you may use `std::string` and you will not have this issue. Or use in/out param, instead of return.

Answer (score 0):

o is the local variable of `output()` so it has scope and life time only inside the function. and as the function is returning a memory address its the deleted memory's address is being returned.

if it had been value which is returned the program would have worked because of the "return by value" method.

If you need the correct output instead of default memory specifier `auto` you need to use something else like `static` or `extern` memory allocation, or dynamic memory allocation.